# Regex to remove non letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to remove non-letters from a string. Would this do it:

```
c = o.replace(o.gsub!(/\W+/, ''))
```

Comment: can you be slightly more descriptive, do you only want a-z? or spaces and certain symbols but not numbers?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just `gsub!` is sufficient:

```
o.gsub!(/\W+/, '')
```

Note that `gsub!` modifies the original `o` object. Also, if the `o` does not contain any non-word characters, the result will be `nil`, so using the return value as the modified string is unreliable.

You probably want this instead:

```
c = o.gsub(/\W+/, '')
```

Comment: aha, gsub modifies the original! that's not cool....is this better then? i don't want to modif orignal. copy = original;
      converted = copy.gsub!(/\W+/, '')
      return converted

Comment: @newbie: The `!` version modifies the original (that's what the `!` means -- it's a sort of "beware, I'm changing the object you called me on" sign). The version without the `!` (as in my second code sample) does what you want -- it doesn't modify the string inplace, but rather returns a copy with the replacements applied

Answer (score 8):

Remove anything that is not a letter:

```
> " sd  190i.2912390123.aaabbcd".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, '')
"sdiaaabbcd"
```

EDIT: as ikegami points out, this doesn't take into account accented characters, umlauts, and other similar characters. The solution to this problem will depend on what exactly you are referring to as "not a letter". Also, what your input will be.

Comment: Zsbán and Ævar beg to differ.

Comment: Hopefully they are not users of this guy's software. On the other hand, you are right on that.

Answer (score 3):

That will work most of the cases, except when `o` initially does not contain any non-letter, in which case `gsub!` will return `nil`.

If you just want a replaced string, it can be simpler:

```
c = o.gsub(/\W+/, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that ruby considers the underscore `_` to be a word character. So if you want to keep underscores as well, this should do it

```
string.gsub!(/\W+/, '')
```

Otherwise, you need to do this:

```
string.gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z]/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `\W` or `\w` to select or delete only characters won't work. `\w` means A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and "_":

```
irb(main):002:0> characters = (' ' .. "\x7e").to_a.join('')
=> " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
irb(main):003:0> characters.gsub(/\W+/, '')
=> "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

So, stripping using `\W` preserves digits and underscores.

If you want to match characters use `/[A-Za-z]+/`, or the POSIX character class `[:alpha:]`, i.e. `/[[:alpha:]]+/`, or `/\p{ALPHA}/`.

The final format is the Unicode property for 'A'..'Z' + 'a'..'z' in ASCII, and gets extended when dealing with Unicode, so if you have multibyte characters you should probably use that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what that `o.replace` is in there for if you have a string:

```
string = 't = 4 6 ^'
```

And you do:

```
string.gsub!(/\W+/, '')
```

You get:

```
t46
```

If you want to get rid of the number characters too, you can do:

```
string.gsub!(/\W+|\d+/, '')
```

And you get:

```
t
```

Answer (score 1):

use Regexp#union to create a big matching object

```
allowed = Regexp.union(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/, " ", "-", ":", ")", "(", ".")
cleanstring = dirty_string.chars.select {|c| c =~ allowed}.join("")
```